# Suggested order for Amazon Prime Doctor Who series

Tags: doctor-who, tv, suggested-order

So I'm nearing the end of the fourth season of Doctor Who on Amazon Prime. And I see there's also a David Tennant Special. And then there are also the Christmas Specials. So, other than watching the regular seasons in order, is there an order to the specials? Like S01, S02,S03, S04, David Tennant special, S05, Christmas Special season 5, S06.

Like I made up the above, but going by the Amazon prime system, is there a correct/better order?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Unfortunately, Amazon has made a dog's breakfast of *Doctor Who*, splitting up random Tennant episodes and the Christmas Specials into separate "shows" that should not be separate, splitting out various other miscellaneous items and combining them with unrelated materials, and even putting seasons in the wrong order. There is no difference between "the David Tennant Specials" and the regular episodes, except that they do not have "regular" episode numbers and for some reason this has motivated Amazon to split them out.

In general, you should watch the episodes [in the order they originally aired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_episodes_(2005%E2%80%93present)#Episodes). This means, starting with Series 1 of the revival (beginning with the Ninth Doctor's introduction in "Rose"), you should watch these seasons and episodes (all names in double quotes are as they appear on Amazon, regardless of what anyone else calls them):

1. "Season 101" through "Season 401" inclusive (all episodes).
2. "The David Tennant Specials" (all episodes except "Doctor Who Confidential: [episode]," which is behind-the-scenes material that you might or might not care to watch).
3. "Season 501"
4. "A Christmas Carol" (from the Christmas Specials).
5. "Season 601"
6. "The Doctor, the Widow and the Wardrobe"
7. "Season 701"
8. "The Snowmen"
9. "Season 702"
10. "The Day of the Doctor" ("50th Anniversary Collection", "Season 50", episode #8)
11. "The Time of the Doctor." (Christmas Specials, "Season 2", episode #2).
12. "Season 801"
13. "Last Christmas"
14. "Season 901"
15. "The Husbands of River Song"
16. "The Return of Doctor Mysterio"
17. "Season 1001"
18. "Twice Upon a Time"
19. "Season 11." Note that "Season 11" appears *above* all of the other seasons, because 11 is less than 101.
20. "Resolution"

Comment: Thanks! This is EXACTLY What I was looking for. Also, my timing is impeccable. As I asked this after watching seasons 1-4. :)

Comment: You can see the broadcast order at sites such as https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_television_stories and http://www.shannonsullivan.com/doctorwho/tv.html.

Comment: This answer is gold! Well done!

Comment: [TheTVDB.com](https://thetvdb.com) is a also a great resource for this. They'll show you the aired order, DVD/Bluray order and several other possible orderings.

Comment: Prime Video [currently lists](https://www.amazon.com/gp/video/detail/B0172XUZCA/) seasons 1 to 11 with no section for "specials". Did they change it after reading this post?

Comment: @JonathanReez: When I follow your link, I see [this](https://imgur.com/iSJXMm4). The specials are not there, and have to be searched for as if they were entirely separate shows. I don't know what Amazon is showing to *you*, however.

Comment: Then perhaps it would be better to link to each episode on Prime Video from your answer?

Comment: @JonathanReez: In general, they are the top Google hits when searching, so that would just be busy work on my part.

Comment: As an example, [here](https://www.amazon.com/Doctor-Who-David-Tennant-Specials/dp/B003LWI7EK) is the amazon link to the "David Tennant Specials"